# Creating AWS account using CDK and Service Catalog return an error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

Im trying to use CDK to prov an account (by using service catalog), here is the code:

```js
this.account = new servicecatalog.CfnCloudFormationProvisionedProduct(this, id, {
      pathId: pathId,
      productId: accountFactoryProductId,
      provisioningArtifactId: artId,
      provisionedProductName: "XXXXX",
      provisioningParameters: [
        { key: 'AccountName', value: name},
        { key: 'AccountEmail', value: email },
        { key: 'ManagedOrganizationalUnit', value: ou },
        { key: 'SSOUserFirstName', value: ssoFirstName },
        { key: 'SSOUserLastName', value: ssoLastName },
        { key: 'SSOUserEmail', value: accountSSOUserEmail },
      ],
    });
```

no matter what Im getting a generic error from AWS saying `Invalid request provided: AWS::ServiceCatalog::CloudFormationProvisionedProduct`

I tried adding permissions and use different roles, nothing worked

Comment: This got resolved, unfortunately the error is super generic and not helping but it was combination of permissions issue and ID that was already exist. My recommendation to anyone that stuck with something similar is start with AWS CLI and only then move to CDK.